# UITableView orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class that inherit from UITableViewController, the only orientation allowed is UIInterfaceOreintationPortrait. In this class I'm using the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to push another view in which landscape orientation is allowed.
The problem is that when I came back from this view in landscape orientation, the TableView is landscape oriented too. I would like too force the TableView to be in portrait mode, how can I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your view controller is implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to constrain the orientation to portrait, it should "snap back" to portrait mode when you come back.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... How are you switching between views? For example, are you using  a UINavigationController with pushViewController:animated: / popViewControllerAnimated: ?

Comment: I'm using pushViewController:animated:

Comment: In that case, I don't know. Maybe try putting a breakpoint or NSLog in your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method to verify that it's really getting called?

Answer (score 0):

If shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation isn't being called, check to see if you have overridden - (id) init.

If you have overridden - (id) init, then you may have forgotten to call super.

Enjoy.